# How to differentiate two different function in Typescript | React

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I have this component in React,

```bash
import { ChangeEvent } from "react";

type SelectProps<T> = {
  options: T[];
  value: number;
  onChange:
    | ((id: number) => void)
    | ((e: React.ChangeEvent<HTMLSelectElement>) => void);
  labelKey: keyof T;
  labelValue: keyof T;
  defaultText: string;
};

/**
 * Select component to show and to select the options.
 * The value that gets selected is the id.
 * The labelKey and labelValue is the keyof T, that is the key of the options.
 *
 * @param options List of objects to display in the Select.
 * @param value The selected value.
 * @param onChange The onChange method to change the value when selected.
 * @param labelKey The text that we want to select when we choose an option.
 * @param labelValue The text that we want to show in the dropdown.
 * @param defaultText The text to display when the value is 0.
 *
 * @returns Select component.
 */
const Select = <T extends object>({
  options,
  value,
  onChange,
  labelKey,
  labelValue,
  defaultText,
}: SelectProps<T>) => {
  const handleOptionChange = (event: ChangeEvent<HTMLSelectElement>) => {
    const selectedValue = parseInt(event.target.value);
    if (typeof onChange === "function") {
      if (onChange instanceof Function) {
        (onChange as (id: number) => void)(selectedValue);
      } else {
        (onChange as (e: React.ChangeEvent<HTMLSelectElement>) => void)(event);
      }
    }
  };

  return (
    <div>
      <select
        value={value}
        onChange={handleOptionChange}
        className="p-2 border w-full cursor-pointer bg-white text-gray-dark border-gray-300 rounded-md focus:outline-none focus:ring-2 focus:ring-blue-500 overflow-y-auto max-h-32"
      >
        <option value={0}>Select a {defaultText}</option>
        {options.map((option) => (
          <option
            key={option[labelKey]}
            value={option[labelKey]}
            className="whitespace-nowrap"
          >
            {option[labelValue]}
          </option>
        ))}
      </select>
    </div>
  );
};

export default Select;
```

In this component, one of the props that is `onChange`, takes two different types of function, and depending on the type of function I want to run the function.
For example when the type is of `((id: number) => void)` I want to run  `(onChange as (id: number) => void)(selectedValue)` and when the type is of `HTMLSelectElement` i want to pass the event.
I can achieve this by passing one of the additional props but is there any way to differentiate these two functions?

I tried a couple of ways like checking type and instance but it didn't work.
Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is tricky (or impossible) to do the way you are approaching this because at runtime both functions become `id => void` because when the code is transpiled all type information is lost. `typeof` and `instanceof` are operations that are evaluated at runtime.

The  dirty way to do it is to add an additional property to `SelectProps`

```
type SelectProps<T> = {
  options: T[];
  value: number;
  onChange?: (id: number) => void;
  onChangeEvent?: (e: React.ChangeEvent<HTMLSelectElement>) => void;
  labelKey: keyof T;
  labelValue: keyof T;
  defaultText: string;
};

const Select = <T extends object>({
  options,
  value,
  onChange,
  onChangeEvent,
  labelKey,
  labelValue,
  defaultText,
}: SelectProps<T>) => {
  const handleOptionChange = (event: ChangeEvent<HTMLSelectElement>) => {
    const selectedValue = parseInt(event.target.value);
    if (onChange !== undefined) {
        onChange(selectedValue);
    } else if (onChangeEvent !== undefined) {
        onChangeEvent(event);
    }
  };
```

You may make it into a type union e.g.

```
type SelectProps<T> = {
  options: T[];
  value: number;
  labelKey: keyof T;
  labelValue: keyof T;
  defaultText: string;
}&({ onChange: (id: number) => void; }|{ onChangeEvent: (e: React.ChangeEvent<HTMLSelectElement>) => void; });
```

This may better clarify that you need one or the other (not none or both)

Answer (score 1):

You can write a custom type guard function like this:

```
const isNumberFunction = (value: any): value is (id: number) => void => {
  return typeof value === "function";
};


const handleOptionChange = (event: ChangeEvent<HTMLSelectElement>) => {
  const selectedValue = parseInt(event.target.value);
  if (typeof onChange === "function") {
    if (isNumberFunction(onChange)) {
      onChange(selectedValue);
    } else {
      onChange(event);
    }
  }
};
```

I think @apokryfos's answer is also right but it's not elegant.
@apokryfos have added an additional property to SelectProps and used a type union to enforce that only one of them is provided. This works, but it makes the component interface more complex and less intuitive. A better way would be to use a generic type parameter for the onChange function, like this:

```
type SelectProps<T> = {
  options: T[];
  value: number;
  onChange: (value: T[keyof T]) => void;
  labelKey: keyof T;
  labelValue: keyof T;
  defaultText: string;
};

const Select = <T extends object>({
  options,
  value,
  onChange,
  labelKey,
  labelValue,
  defaultText,
}: SelectProps<T>) => {
  const handleOptionChange = (event: ChangeEvent<HTMLSelectElement>) => {
    const selectedValue = parseInt(event.target.value);
    const selectedOption = options.find(
      (option) => option[labelKey] === selectedValue
    );
    if (selectedOption) {
      onChange(selectedOption[labelKey]);
    }
  };
};
```

It is more concise, more generic, and more consistent. It avoids adding extra props and using type guards. It also makes the component easier to use and understand.